# Why can't I go to admin REST API request mapping after I have logged in - Spring Boot

Tags: spring, rest, spring-boot, authentication

I have some issues with my REST API, created from Spring Boot and Spring Security.
First I have created my Spring security configuration. As you see here, I have two paths with two different authorizations - USER and ADMIN.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{

    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @Bean
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        // Set the default standard admin and password as admin, if not exist
        User user = userRepository.findByUsername("admin");
        if(user == null) {
            user = new User();
            user.setUserID(0);
            user.setUsername("admin");
            user.setPassword(passwordEncoder().encode("admin"));
            Set<Role> roles = new HashSet<Role>();
            Role role = new Role();
            role.setRoleID(0);
            role.setRolename("ADMIN");
            roles.add(role);
            user.setRoles(roles);
            userRepository.save(user);
        }

        // Connect our database to spring and also with a password encoder
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable();

        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/user/**").authenticated().anyRequest().hasAnyAuthority("ROLE_USER");

        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/admin/**").authenticated().anyRequest().hasAnyAuthority("ROLE_ADMIN");

        http.httpBasic();

        http.formLogin().permitAll();
    }
}
```

And this is my controllers both user and admin.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/admin")
public class AdminController {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @Autowired
    private BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

    @PostMapping("/addUser")
    public String addUser(@RequestBody User user) {
        user.setPassword(passwordEncoder.encode(user.getPassword()));
        userRepository.save(user);
        return "Added user by admin";
    }

    @GetMapping("/adminHello")
    public String adminHello() {
        return "Admin say hello";
    }
}

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/user")
public class UserController {

    @GetMapping("/userHello")
    public String userHello() {
        return "processing..";
    }

}
```

If I try to login to http://localhost:8080/login and write in my password and my username. Then I will be able to go in. Fine!

But these are the problems.

1. If I enter http://localhost:8080/user/userHello with a Admin account, I still get "processing..."
2. If I enter http://localhost:8080/admin/adminHello with a Admin account, I get

   "Whitelabel Error Page

   This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.
   Fri Sep 13 00:23:42 CEST 2019
   There was an unexpected error (type=Forbidden, status=403).
   Forbidden"

Why? Have I forgot something? My Accound have the ADMIN role in the database. Very clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clearly your Role's are not working there is some issue with configuration.

Try this

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

    http.csrf().disable()
    .authorizeRequests()
    .antMatchers("/user/**").hasRole("USER")
    .antMatchers("/admin/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
    .anyRequest().authenticated()
    .and()
    .httpBasic()
    .and()
    .formLogin().permitAll();
}
```

Comment: It works better. The admin account cannot go to the `http://localhost:8080/user/userHello` page - 403 forbidden. But the admin accound can neither go to `http://localhost:8080/admin/adminHello` page - 403 forbidden.

Comment: But it don't work. It just denied my admin accound to go to both admin and user paths. So it works to 50% :)

Comment: Here is the code I'm using. https://github.com/Java-Techie-jt/spring-security-jpa/blob/master/src/main/java/com/javatechie/spring/security/api/service/CustomUserDetails.java

Comment: You think this is correct? https://pastebin.com/rjDMAyDm See the comment.

Comment: Your CustomUserDetailsService need to be updated.  I think you need to store Role post login. Please follow this post 
 https://www.baeldung.com/role-and-privilege-for-spring-security-registration

Comment: This code have more code than needed. I already have a method how to add new user. I think it has something to do with the method `public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities()`

Comment: Now I get the name of the role here! https://pastebin.com/rbf4kf05 But instead I get 404 - Not found when I enter `http://localhost:8080/admin/adminHello` and 403 Forbidden when I enter `http://localhost:8080/user/userHello` So it looks that the roles working now, but cannot find the post and get methods inside the controllers.

Comment: I tried now with Postman and send a GET reponse and now its working! The issue was the `public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities()` :) Thank you for your help and intresst.